# instaling / configuring a local pypi server in CentOS

Tags: local, repository, pypi

I want to install, configure and maintain a local PyPI server with the same number of packages from the upstream pypi server + some custom packages.

I am seeing lots of options like pypiserver / eggbasket etc.. Which is best option?

Also i want a method to pull all packages from upstream pypi server to my local repo so that i can create a repo. pep381run is failing with timeout error. I have made the changes in __init.py for https. Is there anyone who has done something like this.. Please help..

Regards,
Nk